Mostrar grupo de tarjetas entre tarjetas normales: similar a las sugerencias de la app YouTube
Quisiera una ayuda con la presentación de tarjetas en mi código.
Quiero replicar el diseño de la app de YouTube, con las tarjetas normales, y que a su ves, cada cierto números de tarjetas normales, aparece un grupo de 4 tarjetas, que son los videos cortos en Reels.
En mi caso quiero hacer lo mismo, pero con un grupo de dos tarjetas cada cierto intervalo de tarjetas normales.
Esto es lo que no puedo lograr: mostrar cada dos o tres tarjetas normales, el contenedor grupo-tarjeta-mini.
Mis intentos varios sin resultados fueron con forEach, for, map(), pero, me quedé con for, lo cual me aproxima mas a lo que quiero.
En la function tarjetaMini():
const categoriaFiltrada = datos.filter(item => item.tipo.categoria === categoria && item.tipo.clase === 'corto');

let grupos = '';

for (let i = 0; i < categoriaFiltrada.length; i += 2) {
    const grupo = categoriaFiltrada.slice(i, i + 2);
    grupos += `<div class="grupo-tarjeta-mini">`;
    
    grupo.forEach(item => {
        grupos += `
        <div class="tarjeta-mini-vertical">
            <h3>${item.media.titulo}</h3>
        </div>
        `;
    });
    
    grupos += `</div>`;
}
return grupos;

Todos los demás funcionan bien: cada tarjeta se muestra con sus correspondientes tipo y categoría con respecto a la página (sección) que aparece.
Si hay algo en que puedo mejorar, por favor una sugerencia.
Para esta demo, no tengo los estilos responsivo, por lo que se verá desordenado en PC


const datos = [
        { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "narciso", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Narciso recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "margarita", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "margarita", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "margarita", estado: "" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
{ tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "narciso", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Narciso recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "margarita", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "margarita", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "margarita", estado: "" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
 { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "narciso", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Narciso recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "margarita", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "margarita", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "margarita", estado: "" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
];

const listaCategorias = [
{id: 'todos',nombre: "Todos"},
{id: 'aifuz',nombre: "Aifuz"},
{id: 'narciso',nombre: "Narciso"},
{id: 'margarita',nombre: "Margarita"},
{id: 'cortos',nombre: "Cortos"}
];

function tarjetaRecomendado(ito) {
return `<div class="tarjeta tarjeta-recomendado"><h1>Recomendado</h1></div>`;
};

function tarjetaMini(categoria) {
    
    const categoriaFiltrada = datos.filter(item => item.tipo.categoria === categoria && item.tipo.clase === 'corto');

let grupos = '';

for (let i = 0; i < categoriaFiltrada.length; i += 2) {
    const grupo = categoriaFiltrada.slice(i, i + 2);
    grupos += `<div class="grupo-tarjeta-mini">`;
    
    grupo.forEach(item => {
        grupos += `
        <div class="tarjeta-mini-vertical">
            <h3>${item.media.titulo}</h3>
        </div>
        `;
    });
    
    grupos += `</div>`;
}
return grupos;
}
    
function tarjetaNormal(ito) {
        return `<div class="tarjeta"><h1>${ito['media'].titulo}</h1></div>`;
};
    
const nav = document.querySelector("main > nav");
nav.classList.add("yopNavegacion");

const categorias = {};

listaCategorias.forEach(e => categorias[e.id] = {
nombre: e.nombre,
items: []
});

datos.forEach(item => {
categorias.todos.items.push(item);
categorias[item.tipo.categoria].items.push(item);
});
    
let navTitulo = '';
let contenedores = '';

Object.keys(categorias).forEach((id, pos) => {
    
    let activo = pos == 0 ? 'activo' : '';
    navTitulo += `<li class="${activo}" data-pagina="${id}" onclick="paginacionPagina(this)">${categorias[id].nombre}</li>`;
    contenedores += `<div class="pagina ${activo}" id="${id}">`;

    contenedores += `<div class="carretel">${tarjetaRecomendado(id)}</div>`;
    contenedores += tarjetaMini(id);
    
    categorias[id].items.forEach(item => {
            contenedores += tarjetaNormal(item);
            
    });

contenedores += `</div>`;
});

nav.innerHTML = `<div class="ul">${navTitulo}</div>`;

const section = document.createElement("section");
    section.classList.add("paginacion");
    section.setAttribute("id","paginacion");
    section.innerHTML = contenedores;

const append = document.querySelector("main");
append.appendChild(section);

const navItems = document.querySelectorAll("nav li");
const paginaSections = document.querySelectorAll(".pagina");

navItems.forEach(item => {
item.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const targetPage = e.target.getAttribute("data-pagina");
    paginaSections.forEach(page => page.classList.remove("activo"));
    document.getElementById(targetPage).classList.add("activo");
});
});
    
function tarjetaRecomendado(ito) {
        return `
        <div class="tarjetas">
        
        ${categorias[ito].items.filter(item => item.tipo.estado === 'recomendado').map(item => `
         <div class="tarjeta tarjeta-recomendado">
         <h1>${item.media.titulo}</h1>
        </div>`
        
        ).join('')}
        </div>
        `;
        
}
* {box-sizing: border-box}
    body {margin: 0}

.yopNavegacion {
    display: flex;
position: sticky;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto
} .yopNavegacion .ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap
} .yopNavegacion li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 1rem;
background-color: grey
}

.paginacion {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
            display: grid;
     grid-auto-flow: column;
            grid-auto-columns: 100%;
            gap: .50rem
} .pagina {
    display: none;
} .pagina.activo {
    display: block;
    animation: feadIn 0.6s ease-in-out
} @keyframes feadIn {
    0% {opacity: 0}
    100% {opacity: 1}
}

.tarjeta {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
        padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 0.3rem;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
        background-color: lightgrey
    } .tarjeta-recomendado {
        width: 250px;
    height: 150px
}
    
.carretel {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
overflow-x: auto;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 1rem
}

.carretel .tarjetas {
display: flex;
gap: 1rem
}
    
.grupo-tarjeta-mini {
display: flex;
gap: 1rem;
margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
padding: 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
background-color: red
}

.tarjeta-mini-vertical {
    display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
width: 180px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 0.3rem;
background-color: lightgrey
}
<body>

 <main>
 
 <nav></nav>
    
 </main>
</body>




Entiendo que tu problema es solo intercalar tarjetas, yo usaría 3 listas:

items: lista de elementos filtrados por categoría
cortos: lista de elementos (de la lista items)  de la clase "cortos"
normal: lista de elementos (de la lista items) de la clase "normal"

Luego recorro la lista items, pero voy sacando los elementos desde las listas cortos y normal cuando corresponda
¿y cuando corresponde?
Esto queda a tu criterio, puede ser random o cada n elementos. Digamos que es la última opción, para ello usas el operador % --> if(i % n === 0)
Además yo utilizaría una función generadora, que si bien no es imprescindible, creo que queda más ordenado.


const datos = [
        { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "narciso", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Narciso recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "margarita", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "margarita", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "margarita", estado: "" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
{ tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "narciso", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Narciso recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "margarita", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "margarita", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "margarita", estado: "" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
 { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "narciso", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Narciso recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "margarita", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "margarita", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "corto", categoria: "aifuz", estado: "recomendado" }, media: { titulo: "Aifuz recomendado", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
        { tipo: { clase: "normal", categoria: "margarita", estado: "" }, media: { titulo: "Margarita", url: "../videos/demo.mp4" } },
];

const listaCategorias = [
{id: 'todos',nombre: "Todos"},
{id: 'aifuz',nombre: "Aifuz"},
{id: 'narciso',nombre: "Narciso"},
{id: 'margarita',nombre: "Margarita"},
{id: 'cortos',nombre: "Cortos"}
];
//====================================

// cat: categoría
// n: cada n elementos normales se muestran 2 cortos
function* getItem(cat, n) {

  const items = cat === "todos" ? datos : datos.filter(a => a.tipo.categoria === cat);
  const cortos = items.filter(a => a.tipo.clase === "corto");
  const normal = items.filter(a => a.tipo.clase === "normal");


  for (let i = 0; i < items.length;) {
    if (dato = normal.shift()) yield dato; i++; //normal
      
    if (i % n === 0) {
        if (corto = cortos.shift()) yield corto; i++; // corto 1
        if (corto = cortos.shift()) yield corto; i++; // corto 2
    }
  }
}
//======

for (let i of getItem("todos", 2)) {
  console.log(i);
}



Notar que en el último for se imprimen los elementos en el orden establecido. En tu caso, a partir de este for vas creando las "tarjetas" que imprimes en pantalla

Gracias. Me mareo un poco para adaptar a mi codigo pero funciona
